# How to change test size of Tabs in a Tabhost?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, text-size

How can I change text size of tab labels. I know that there are lots of similar questions but I am very new to android platform and not using android.support.design.widget.TabLayout. Every example about this problem in stackoverflow or in other sites contains TableLayout. How can I solve this with Tabhost?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.mobiders.activity.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tab_host"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/hscrollview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fl_interceptor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" />

<include
    layout="@layout/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this programmatically. In your activity where you are using tabhost, use th following code

```
     TabHost tabhost = getTabHost();
            for(int i=0;i<tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++) 
            {
                TextView tv = (TextView) tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
                int textSize = 14;
                tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,textSize );
            }
```

Then, on tab change you can change the textsize, by using the following code:

```
        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

                for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {

                    TextView tv = (TextView) tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title); //Unselected Tabs
                    int textSize = 14;
                    tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,textSize );
                }


                TextView tv = (TextView) tabhost.getCurrentTabView().findViewById(android.R.id.title); //for Selected Tab
                    int textSize2 = 14;
                    tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,textSize2);


            }
        });
```